# In java, why uninitialized char is OK but not String

Tags: java, initialization

In the following code, I get a compilation error if I leave the String name uninitialized, but the char initial has no problem being left uninitialized. Why is this difference in behaviour?

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char initial;
        String name;
        for (String input: args) {
            name += input;
            initial = input.charAt(0);
            System.out.print(initial + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to do += to name which is null. YOu should be able to do assignment like name = "abc" without problem.

Answer (score 10):

You're assigning the char before you read it (in the `System.out.println()` line), but you're not assigning the String before you read it, which happens in the `name += input` line.

Answer (score 3):

```
name += input;
```

is equivalent to

```
name = name + input;
```

You are using `name` (a local variable) without initializing it. and this is cause of error. specifically, you are trying to concat un-initialized `name` with `input`.

```
initial = input.charAt(0);
```

Here, you are initializing it before using it in print statement. hence no error.

Answer (score 2):

The first time initial is used it is set to a value:

```
initial = input.charAt(0);
```

The first time name is used it is using a null value in the calculation:

```
name += input; // is equivalent to
name = null + input;
```

Since name has not been initialized (see meaning of +=).

Answer (score 0):

char is a primitive, these are initialized automatically (in case of char to \u0000). Now that you did not initialize name, name+= input makes no sense. You probably meant to start name with a value of "".

Comment: that is valid for instance variables, not local: refering to the automatic initialization.